# JS How to loop through an array and slice/create a new array at every empty element in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know this should be simple, but I can't figure it out I'm probably too sleep deprived right now.

I have an array like this:

```
['a 3', 'b', 'c 145', '', 'e', 'f 98', '', 'g 1', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla']
```

I want to make columns by splitting at every '' so it would look like this:

```
[['a 3', 'b', 'c 145'], ['e', 'f 98'], ['g 1', 'h'], ['bla', 'bla']]
```

I've tried all kinds of things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an updated approach that uses reduce and starts a new array each time it encounters an element with value `''`

```js
const arr = ['a3', 'b', 'c145', '', 'e', 'f98', '', 'g0', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla'];
let start = 0;
const out = arr.reduce((p, c, i) => {
  const isLast = i === arr.length - 1;
  if (c === '' || isLast) {
     let end = isLast ? arr.length : i;
     p.push(arr.slice(start, end))
     start = i+1;
  }
  return p;
}, []);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the elements can have spaces in the name too

Comment: Thanks for the really fast answer

Comment: As with the other `reduce` answer, doesn't using values external to the function defeat the purpose?

Comment: @jered Agreed. Lots of these answers are overcomplicated.

Comment: @jered I'm not sure I understand how it's "defeating the purpose". What purpose is being defeated by using an external value?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like this:

```
const arr = ['a 3', 'b', 'c 145', '', 'e', 'f 98', '', 'g 1', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla']
const output = [[]]
arr.forEach(i => {
  if(i === ''){ 
    output.push([]) 
  }else{
    output[output.length - 1].push(i)
  }
})
```

Basically you just step through and push to a new array if a `''` is found. Simplest answer imo.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jupspg9n/)

---

If you really want to do it with `reduce` you can modify it to do something like the following:

```
const arr = ['a 3', 'b', 'c 145', '', 'e', 'f 98', '', 'g 1', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla']
const output = arr.reduce((a, i) => {
  if(i === ''){
    a.push([])
  }else{
    a[a.length - 1].push(i)
  }
  return a
}, [[]])
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jupspg9n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['a3', 'b', 'c145', '', 'e', 'f98', '', 'g0', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla'],
    array = [];
    res = arr.reduce(function(s,a){
      if (a != '') { 
        array.push(a);
      } else {
        s.push(array);
        array = [];
      }
      return s;
    }, []);
    !array.length ? null : res.push(array);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: FYI, the last array `[bla, bla]` is missing in your solution

Comment: @RobM. Yep indeed. Thanks xd

Comment: I'm trying to write a `reduce` solution too, but IMO it's cheating to use an array external to the reduce. :P

Comment: See mine. It has a simple reduce answer.

Comment: @Kinduser Its not external, it is part of the reduce function!

Comment: @Kinduser I also find it interesting that you think a nested (multidimensional) array is bad, when that is the exact structure of the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer

```
//given example
var inital_arr = ['a3', 'b', 'c145', '', 'e', 'f98', '', 'g0', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla'];

function process_arr(array){
    //will be returned once function is complete
    var output = [];

  //holds array columns until the next ''
  var holding_var = [];

  //goes through entire array
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

    //runs if string has content
    if(array[i].length > 0){
        holding_var.push(array[i]);

      //runs if string length is 0
    } else if(array[i].length <= 0){

      //moves the holding array into the output array
        output.push(holding_var);

      //resets the holding array
      holding_var = [];
    }
  }
  return output;
}

//debuging to show it working
console.log(process_arr(inital_arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer an an inner array and a simple iteration

```js
function makeArray(arr) {
  outer = [];
  inner = [];
  arr.map(item => {
    if (item !== '') {
      inner.push(item);
    } else {
      outer.push(inner);
      inner = [];
    }
  });
  return outer;
}
const arr = ['a 3', 'b', 'c 145', '', 'e', 'f 98', '', 'g 1', 'h', '', 'bla', 'bla'];
const res = makeArray(arr);
console.log(res);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vijeyo/edit?js,console)